# gnuplot xtics with underscores in enhanced mode

Tags: gnuplot, axis-labels

I need to print named xtics in extended mode. The problem is that the names stored in "selected_indices" contain underscores. To print them as underscores in extended mode, the underscores must be preceded by three backslashes. How can I insert these three backslashes automatically when I add the xtics to a plot?

original:

```
n_indices = words(selected_indices)
selected_indices = "A_a B_b"
print selected_indices
```

wanted:

```
selected_indices = "A\\\_a B\\\_b"
print selected_indices

set xtics ( '' 1 )
set for [i=1:n_indices] xtics add ( sprintf("{/:Bold %s}", word( selected_indices, i ) ) i )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing which comes to my mind is simply to replace the `_` by `\_`.
Mind the difference with single and double quotes, either `"\\\_"`or `'\_'`.

In the following script, a function is defined to replace the first underscore (`_`) in a string by backslash + underscore (`\_`). With this, you can "un"enhance the underscore for subscript, but still use `^` for subscript. Maybe there are better solutions.

**Script:**

```
### unenhance underscore in enhanced textmode
reset session

$Data <<EOD
A_a^1   1
B_b^2   2
C_c^3   3
EOD

set offset 1,1,1,1
set key noautotitle
set style fill solid 0.4

ueus(s) = s[1:c=strstrt(s,'_')-1].'\_'.s[c+2:]   # unenhance underscore

plot $Data u 0:2:xtic(ueus(strcol(1))) w boxes
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

In case you have multiple underscores in your string, you can replace them all by the following function:

```
# replace all `_` with `\_`
rpus(s) = (c='', sum[j=1:strlen(s)] (c=c.(s[j:j] eq '_' ? '\_' : s[j:j]), 0), c)
print rpus("A_b_cde_fgh_12^3")
```

**Result:**

```
A\_b\_cde\_fgh\_12^3
```

Comment: Your solution inspired me to look for some C functions before I realized I could do this for a whole string with a system call: ueus(s) = system( "echo \"".s."\" | sed 's/_/\\\\_/g'" ) Only figuring out the required number of backslashes was difficult.

Comment: @magfan in this specific case, I would consider a system call with an additional external program as an "overkill". If possible, I prefer gnuplot-only solutions.

Comment: That is true. But I discovered that among the hundreds of labels in my tables, there are some with more than one underscore. I thought of doing a recursive search from the end of the string to replace all occurrences in one pass. But with this approach I simply had no success.